# How to print out a cell?

Tags: matlab, cell

In MATLAB (R2015b) I have a cell `C` (1x4 cell, with 4 columns):

```
C = [4x1 double] [4x1 double] {4x1 cell} {4x1 cell}
```

And when I call `C` I get the printout above, but I want MATLAB to write it as:

`[10]   [31.2]   'TRS'   'BLU'
[12]   [34.2]   'TRS'   'BLU' 
[13]   [33.5]   'TRS'   'BLU' 
[14]   [34.8]   'TRS'   'BLU'`

I.e. a 4x4 cell. How can I get this printout? Thanks

Comment: Does `celldisp` kind of do what you want?

Comment: No, not really since it prints out each one row separately. Also I want the brackets around my double values, i.e. [10], not only 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the first two elements to cell arrays and then you can horizontally contatenate them and display them

```
[num2cell(c{1}), num2cell(c{2}), c{3:end}]
```

Comment: YES! THANK YOU! Clarification for future readers; I needed to convert elements into cells.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can work

```
for i=1:numel(c)
    fprintf('%g %g %s %s\n',c{1}(i),c{2}(i),c{3}{i},c{4}{i})
end
```